# How to look up and assign values between two files to a new file using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap, hashtable, assign

I'm trying to write a script that converts every allele (A,T,G, or C) in my file to 0 or 1 depending on its ancestral state at that position, which is saved in another file "DAF.txt"
I have two files. They are ordered based on genomic position but contain different information.

File 1: Alleles

```
    1 2 3 4 ...900000
    A G T C G
    G A G G C
    A A T C C
```

DAF.txt: Ancestral status

```
    1 A
    2 A
    3 T
    4 G
    ...900000 C
```

DAF.txt serves as a reference of sorts for File 1. Every row of file 1 must be compared column by column with each row in DAF.txt
If the letter in column 1,row 1 in file 1 == the letter in row 1 in DAF.txt, then I need to replace that letter or print "0" to a new file in its place, file.hap, else if the letters in the files don't match at that position, then print "1" to file.hap. The order matters. file.hap must be in the same order as file 1.

In the end, file.hap should look like:

```
    1 2 3 4 ...900000
    0 1 0 1 1
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 1 0
```

Any suggestions for doing this in perl? It's a big file...

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough memory, you can store the ancestral alleles in an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $DAF, '<', 'DAF.txt' or die $!;
open my $AL,  '<', 'alleles' or die $!;

my @ancestral;
while (<$DAF>) {
    chomp;
    push @ancestral, $_;
}

<$AL>;                        # Skip the header.
while (my $al_line = <$AL>) {
    my @alleles = split ' ', $al_line;
    for my $i (0 .. $#alleles) {
        print $alleles[$i] eq $ancestral[$i] ? 0 : 1;
        print ' ' unless $i == $#alleles;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you don't, split the file into N files and just open, check, close, next. That's one easy solution to a memory issue.

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: "Use of uninitialized value in string eq at test.pl line 17, <$AL> line 1" for every line in the file. To clarify, neither file has a header; I just put the header in the question to keep track what what each column represented. So why the error? Also, I need to write the converted output to a new file, file.hap, but am unsure where to put that.

Comment: I tried adding a header to each file and I still get the same error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong =(

Comment: @user3482899: Does the DAF file contain line numbers as shown in your sample?

Comment: Ah. No, it does not. It literally just contains one allele per row. How does that change things?

Comment: @user3482899: Try the updated code. If the line contains just one value, there's no need to `split` it.

Comment: That works beautifully! Thank you! How would I write the converted output to a new file, new file.hap?

Comment: @user3482899: You can just redirect the output of the original: `perl script.pl > file.hap`.